# Lottery with consecutive numbers

Tags: combinatorics

A lottery is drawing 7 out of 34 balls. No number can be drawn twice. What is the probability that the lottery contains at least two consecutive numbers (for instance 11 and 12)?

Comment: Related: http://curiouscheetah.com/BlogMath/consecutive-numbers/

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your post to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Let us go for the probability that the lottery does *not* contain any consecutive numbers.

Let set of drawn numbers be $D=\{d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4,d_5,d_6,d_7\}$ with $1\leq d_1<d_2<\dots<d_7\leq34$.

Without constraints there are $\binom{34}7$ possibilities for $D$.

Under the condition that there are no consecutives we can write:

- $d_{1}=b_{1}+1$
- $d_{i}=d_{i-1}+b_{i}+2$ for $i=2,3,4,5,6,7$

where the $b_{i}$ are non-negative integers.

Addition on both sides leads to the condition $34\geq\sum_{i=1}^{7}b_{i}+13$ or equivalently $$\sum_{i=1}^{8}b_{i}=21$$
where $b_{8}$ again denotes a non-negative integer.

Applying stars and bars we find there are $\binom{21+8-1}{8-1}=\binom{28}{7}$
possibilities for the $b_{i}$.

So the probability on no consecutives is $\frac{\binom{28}7}{\binom{34}7}$ and the probability on at least one pair of consecutives is:$$1-\frac{\binom{28}7}{\binom{34}7}$$